Litigating with IRS without ITIN or SSN
I am a nonresident alien who has never been to the US. No business there either, never, in any shape or form. I'm currently in a dispute over my tax situation with the IRS and it seems like i will have to litigate in tax or district court. However, I have no ITIN or SSN and IRS will take up to a year to process an ITIN application even if I file one. Is it possible to file a petition at either Tax or District court and participate in the litigation procedure without having SSN or ITIN? My case concerns gift tax btw. I plan to file and explain my legal position to IRS but not pay and then after they issue notice of deficiency attempt at tax court or may be district court if I decide so

What did you attorney say?

You should file a gift tax return (form 709) to reflect your position. Form 709 instructions for line 3 (SSN) says that if you do not already have an SSN or ITIN, the IRS will assign you an IRSN.


I am a nonresident alien who has never been to the US. No business there either, never, in any shape or form. I'm currently in a dispute over my tax situation with the IRS and it seems like i will have to litigate in tax or district court.

You're not currently in dispute since you're not currently in any pending litigation or audit. You are looking at a prospect of dispute, given what you described I can't imagine on what basis.

I plan to file and explain my legal position to IRS but not pay and then after they issue notice of deficiency attempt at tax court or may be district court if I decide so

You can't sue in a District Court without paying - you can only file claims of refund there, which means you have to have paid first. Objecting to the notice of deficiency is only possible in Tax Court.

Is it possible to file a petition at either Tax or District court and participate in the litigation procedure without having SSN or ITIN?

Yes. But it is unlikely that any notice will be issued to you by the IRS without any TIN assigned.

I asked you in the comments, and I'll mention it again: if your intention is litigation, you should have an attorney before you even start. It doesn't sound like you've talked it over with an attorney yet. Clearly, you have an unusual situation which you intend to challenge. Doing so without a proper legal counsel sounds to me like a dumb idea.

Thanks for the response. Yes, I'm in search for an attorney rn. And just to clarify. Say I file at tax court after getting my SND and then lose in tax court and then appeal and lose that as well. Is i then possible to pay the tax and then attempt at district court or court of fed. claims? Or am I barred from doing so after I lose at tax court?

You'll need to discuss it with your attorney. Some tax court cases cannot be appealed. Others may be appealed with the US circuit appeals court in your circuit, which would also be binding on the district court.
